# is this a list or an array of what type? values without commas in between? and can be represented as dots or line?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

this a 2D array can be represented on two axis

```
array([[-3.83458347,  6.09210705],
       [-4.62571831,  5.54296865],
       [-2.87807159, -7.48754592],
       ...,
       [-3.709726  , -7.77993633],
       [-8.44553266, -1.83519866],
       [-4.68308431,  6.91780744]])
```

this 1D array can be represented on one axis:

```
array([ 0.        ,  0.20266794,  0.39692415,  0.57470604,  0.72863478,
        0.85232157,  0.94063279,  0.98990308,  0.99808748,  0.96484631,
        0.89155923,  0.78126802,  0.63855032,  0.46932961,  0.2806294 ,
        0.08028167, -0.12339814, -0.32195632, -0.50715171, -0.67129779,
       -0.80758169, -0.91034694, -0.97532829, -0.99982867, -0.9828312 ,
       -0.92504137, -0.82885774, -0.6982724 , -0.53870529, -0.35677924,
       -0.16004509,  0.04333173,  0.24491007,  0.43632343,  0.6096272 ,
        0.75762842,  0.8741843 ,  0.9544572 ,  0.99511539,  0.99447137,
        0.95255185,  0.8710967 ,  0.75348673,  0.60460332,  0.43062587,
        0.23877532,  0.0370144 , -0.16628279, -0.36267843, -0.54402111])
```

How to represent this in input space and does it havea name?

```
[ 4.02775036 10.70202291  5.54216027]
[ 9.7303528   7.20866583 17.44505393]
[ 4.06676751 11.11317999  5.15897011]
[ 5.28441816  8.93146403 13.31415736]
[ 6.29310516 13.46792103  2.66429839]
```

it has no comma between  the values

it is an output from this :

```
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=1500, centers=3, \
n_features=2, random_state=800)
centroids = [[-6,2],[3,-4],[-5,10]]
for x in X[105:110]:
    cl = cdist(x.reshape(1, -1), centroids).squeeze()
    print(cl)
```

Comment: These are five 1-D arrays

Comment: but it has no commas in between the values !! not like a normal numpy array with 
and should I represent it as points? in scatter

Comment: If you `print(any_numpy_array)`, it will be printed without commas. You can check the type of objects using `print(type(cl))`.

Comment: The string representation of an object is... **a representation**, it cannot necessarily be used directly as input but rather is made for humans to appreciate the meaning of an object

Comment: the upper one is also 1D array represeting a vector ,what make the representation different when there's no commas between the values? this on is 1D array as @ForceBru said, does it represnt a vector  or data points ?

Comment: @user4556432, one representation is `print(repr(the_array))`, the other one is `print(str(the_array))`. Two representations are needed because one can be copied&pasted as valid Python code, while the other one may be easier to read for humans. 1D arrays can be treated as vectors or as collections of data points (then each data point is a single number).

Comment: @ForceBru, the `repr` of an object does not have to be executable as Python code.  It just gives more information than the `str`, often including some indication of class.  In the case of an `ndarray`, it includes the name `array` (I always have to add a `np.` when copy-n-pasting`), and may include ellipsis.

Comment: Don't count on the print of an array to be useable as a `input` string.  `np.savetxt` can be used to write a 2d array to a file which can later be loaded with `np.genfromtxt`.  `arr.tolist()` makes a (nested) list whose `str` can be parsed.  But `np.save/load` is the best way of saving and loading a numpy to/from a file.